# How to pass TEXT Array [ ] to a postgres function?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have this function which has been translated from oracle to postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myblah ( values TEXT[], evalues TEXT[], p_pid bigint, c_id bigint, pr_id bigint, p_name TEXT, p_use text default 'N') 
RETURNS VOID
AS $body$
```

and I am trying to call this function in order to test. But I am having issue inserting the array parameter, unsure of the syntax and cannot find anything to show me.

for example I am trying this but it is not acceptable syntax:

```
select myblah (TEXT['hello','whynot','jasmine'], 43423, 434234,534534,'fggffgfg','N');
```

the error is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: select myblah(TEXT['hello','whynot','jasmin...
```

however removing the ',' does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [need](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) the `array` keyword:

```
select myblah (array['hello','whynot','jasmine'], 43423, 434234,534534,'fggffgfg','N');
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) will tell you, there are two options:

```
'{string 1,string 2}'
```

or

```
ARRAY['string1', 'string 2']
```